# Heroku + node.js error at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: node.js, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm building a simple app, it works when 100% local, it works on heroku with local, when I try to access from heroku it crashes. I get this error

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

I tried a few things already

- I change the harcoded port in my app.js to a process.env.PORT
- I did heroku restart
- I did most of the stuff people say about this issue on stackoverflow

But I still get the same error.

My code is on this plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/1nORDleC7pmFphEpXcGO

Also I have some issue with my .env file as it contain only this

using

```
cat .env
```

I get this

```
TIMES=2
```

How do I add stuff in it, I want to add 2 keys,
And if I have only this in my .env how does this app.listen know the port...

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Edit : I have another hint, looking at the logs my process crashes right after it started. Like 2 seconds later.

So I

```
Heroku restart
```

I get

```
Starting process with command...
```

And immediately after I get

```
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 0
```

Why... :'(

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the issue !!

So in my Procfile I wrote

```
web : blablabla blablabla node app.js
```

And the issue was that I needed to delete the " : " before blablabla because the heroku console could't read it !

Now it works amazing !